# Sequence of tenses for modal verbs?

Tags: tense, modal-verbs, sequence-of-tenses

*Would*, *could*, and *might* can be used to express possibility or uncertainty in the present or future (they are the "softer" and more "indirect", or more "polite" forms of *will*, *can*, and *may* in this usage, I believe), but I don't know whether the subordinate clauses should follow the rules of the sequence of tenses or not.

Let me explain what I mean:

> (1) "I am not sure I want to go to the party. But if Betty **invites/invited** me, I would go."
> =>I want to use "would" to express future uncertainty.

> (2) "This thing is mysterious. I would imagine Tom **is/was** able to explain."
> =>I want to use "would" to express present uncertainty in my thinking

> (3) "I have an idea. We could tell him that we **will/would** not let the secret out so that he **will/would** trust us"
> =>I want to use "could" to express future uncertainty or possibility.

Does the sequence of tenses apply in scenarios where we use *would*, *could*, *might* in a present or future sense?

In cases of expressing possibility or being more indirect, do we just treat *would*, *could*, and *might* the same way as *will*, *can*, and *may* in terms of the sequence of tenses?

Answer (score 0):

I might have some helpful things to say about these.

> (1) "I am not sure I want to go to the party. But if Betty invites/invited me, I would go."

I'll point out that it is somewhat important here to not choose *But if Betty invited me, I will go.* ***unless*** you specifically mean *if Betty has already invited me, I will go.* - and because we are using "will", this is a certain future.

> (2) "This thing is mysterious. I would imagine Tom is/was able to explain."

Here, be careful not to use ***was*** with *I would imagine* - don't say *I would imagine Tom was able to explain.* It places his ability strictly in the past.  You might see something like, for example, *I wouldn't be surprised if Tom was able to explain* though, because *was* matches with the *surprised* (which isn't in the past, but is a hypothetical)

> (3) "I have an idea. We could tell him that we will/would not let the secret out so that he will/would trust us"

You would probably use *tell him that we will* - it is a stronger assurance, and you are able to give it; if you do not, it seems a bit weak.  Phrasing choices later might influence this a bit, though.  Somewhat similarly, it is a bit better to use *will* for the second choice, too; this is your predicted outcome, so your listener assumes you could be wrong; you can't know the future.  So just go all out, and claim the result you predict.  It's normal; you're plainly trying to convince them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you mean the subordinate clause of (1) can be in present tense or any other tense according to what I want to say, right? Do you mean that the tenses in subordinate clauses in the examples isn't forced to be "backshifted"? And they can be any tenses according to the meaning I want to convey? For example, if I use "would" in (3), I sound more unsure about it, but using "will" sounds like I have confidence that the thing will happen, am I right?

Comment: So can I say when we use them in cases like these, we can see these modal verbs as "will", "can", and "may" so that we don't have to backshift verbs in the subordinate clauses?

Comment: Yes, I think you are understanding.  I'll read it again carefully to be sure.

Comment: Here is one: *If Betty invites me, I will go.* - you know if you will go or not, so it is weird to use *would*

Comment: And *If Betty invited me I would have gone* is an allowable simplification of *If Betty had invited me I would have gone *

Comment: But usually you don't choose *If Betty invited me, I would go.* - I guess you can, but normally I do only if I follow with some other hypothetical - *If Betty invited me, I would go, if you gave me a ride.*

Comment: There; I deleted one comment because rephrasing would be more helpful.

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand the case (1). So is my understanding of (2) and (3) (which is in the first reply) correct? By the way how about "I would give the money back when she tells/told me the truth." I want to express "I will probably give the money back when she tells me the truth." but I used "would" instead of "will probably." Yes, I found it. The core of my confusion is whether I can use "would", "could", "might" the same way as "will probably" or "can probably", which don't require tense-backshifting. So can I use them that way?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118683/discussion-between-justin-stafford-and-vincentlin).